# Android : Selenium driver.getPageSource() equivalent for android app

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, robotium

I build an automation test project for android using [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/). However, at one point, I am in need to look at the source code of the current app window.

I was wondering if there is any way to access the android app code at particular window (say after filling the search wizard, the application takes us to product search result page and there I need to look for the complete source code). Just like we have it for desktop sites when we use [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) and do `driver.getPageSource()`.

Any other alternative way would also be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way or an easy way to do the sort of equivalent you say you want, however there is a tool that might be of use and what I think you will actually want.

Its called the [hierarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html), it allows you to view the views that are currently on the screen and therefore help you to understand what you can use to search the screen to find it via robotium. You will probably have to use this on an emulator (certain phones it does work on however).

Comment: Yes. But you can't use hierarchy viewer within test case right? The views at front end could easily be accessed by this but the ultimate goal is to look inside.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question I think. I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you trying to look inside for? If you really want the source code, the answer is no. That is not possible, your application is Java compiled down to dex code, unlike html which is free to view. You can decompile an app to view the code but again not within your test.